# Tikz and basic expansion problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion

I can barely understand how LaTeX uses expansion, and here is another example where I cannot solve my problem.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myPos}[2]{$(current page.north west) + (#1\paperwidth,-#2\paperheight)$}

\newcommand{\addWholePictureG}[5]{%
  \belowCrop{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=#3]() at (#4)
        {\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2,keepaspectratio]{#5}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}

% Works:
\addFillPictureG{6cm}{6cm}{center}{$(current page.north west) + (.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight)$}{}{20160724_184636.jpg}
\addFillPictureG{6cm}{6cm}{center}{current page.south}{}{20160724_184636.jpg}

% Does *not* work
\addFillPictureG{6cm}{6cm}{center}{\myPos{.5}{.5}}{}{20160724_184636.jpg}

\end{document}
```

`myPos` is supposed to be a simple replacement, but the replacement seems to be pretty bad because after it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named $(current page is known.

--- TeX said ---

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 ...p=0pt,anchor=center]() at (\myPos{.5}{.5})
                                                  {Hi};
```

I tried to play with `expandafter` stuff, but with no result. Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do 0.5 0.5 do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution here is to use the `at` key in the node options and use the `.expanded` handler. This will effectively `\edef` the argument:

```
\newcommand{\addFillPictureG}[5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=#3, at/.expanded={(#4)}]
      {\includegraphics[width=#1,height=#2,keepaspectratio]{#5}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

So, something like:

```
\addFillPictureG{6cm}{6cm}{center}{\myPos{.5}{.5}}{some_image.jpg}
```

Should work (provided `some_image.jpg` is available on the file system).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that tikzpicture looks for the whole `($()$)` before expanding the commands inside its environment.

So you could do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myPos}[2]{#1,#2}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]() at ($(\myPos{5}{3})$){Hi(5,3)};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]() at ($(\myPos{0}{0})$){Hi(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The included in ($()$) has to be two or three numbers for the coordinates of the point.

**Edit:**

A second way to do it is to use `\xdef` or \newcommand to expand just the point like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myPos}[2]{#1,#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \xdef\myPoint{\myPos{5}{3}}
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center](A) at (\myPoint) {Hi(5,3)};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]() at (\myPos{0}{0}){Hi(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For more complicated calculations you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myPos}{current page.center}
\newcommand{\myP}[2]{#1,#2}
\begin{document}

% Works:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center]() at ($(current page.center)$){Hi};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center](A) at ($(\myPos)+(\myP{9}{3})$) {Hi(9,3)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Wait for others too because I am sure there are much more ways.

Comment: Thank you for this first idea, but indeed if you find a way to avoid to manually write the $()$ I'd be  very happy, because I'd like it to be quite transparent for the user.

Comment: The second example does not using math mode at all but it is a simple point. You can use it for current page.center but you need the third way for adding numbers. Please be more specific about what the user will give and what you want to calculate after user's input

Comment: I uploaded my question to put more specific code. But I'm thinking that everything that work without the $()$ should also work with the $()$, so your solution should always work... Thank you !

Comment: Welcome... And thank you for the interesting question too... I will keep it to see other answers from more experienced users.